# AstroPosition[] years of validity

Tags: astronomy

I'm using online version 13.3(?) attempting to compute the position of Jupiter. It looks like "AstroPosition[]" only returns values for years between 1900 and 2050. Outside of these dates, it returns the input. Wolfram|Alpha however, returns a position.

Wasn't able to confirm this in the documentation or a Google search.

Is there a range of validity for the years going into "AstroPosition[]" or did I miss something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Can you please include the exact code you are using so that others can replicate the behaviour? Also, the version number is available if you evaluate `$Version`.

Comment: Hm, that is indeed weird. Sometimes, indeed, for a given year, the download of ephemeris of the Solar System begins for the given period, but then the input is returned ([example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYqZS.png), [example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKC9b.png), [example 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJhFL.png), [input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxac7.png)).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Domen. I tried several other cases but did not get the message that it was downloading ephemeris data. Even tried Mars for 1000 bc and did not get an indication of an ephemeris download.

Comment: You need to post exact code you tried and the outputs. And the inputs for Alpha.